# Does drupal or joomla allow a combination node.js and socket.io with php?

Tags: php, drupal, node.js, joomla, socket.io

I'm looking into the development of a site where socket use is a must for real time updates. I understand with wordpress it is difficult to incorporate node.js and socket.io and was wondering if this is the case with drupal. **Specifically could I incorporate node.js and socket.io with php? What specific steps would I need to take?** I appreciate the help and of course if you give me a good answer, I'll rate you up.

Answer (score 2):

There are currently Node.js modules that connect to Drupal, Joomla, and WordPress. I wrote the one for Joomla: https://github.com/jlleblanc/nodejs-joomla You can find all of these through NPM. First, you would download one of these modules, then you would also download the Socket.io module. Then you would write server side code connecting the CMS to Socket.io. Finally, you would write client-side code to talk to the socket running in Node.

Answer (score 1):

You can have it separated and since you want some client-server communication with node.js, you can have it - outside Drupal (this is the easiest and cleanest way).

**CMS you use (be it Drupal or Wordpress) does not limit your JavaScript from using socket.io and node.js** for the calls you want to be made outside the CMS server-side code. You can eg. read the same database Drupal/Wordpress does, but using Node.js and returning the results directly to the client-side JavaScript script.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Socket.IO with whatever technology you like, but you need to think of them as 2 separate parts that need to communicate.

I see 2 solutions for Socket.IO to communicate with an external service (Drupal, Joomla, Wordpress, whatever):

1) Making a rest API for your Socket.IO application (for example using Express for the API layer and then passing messages to Socket.IO with an EventEmitter).

2) The better solution in my opinion is to use a message queue like Redis, RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ. The Drupal website would send a message down the channel to Socket.IO and then Socket.IO would send that message to the client(s).

If you are creating a system that needs authentication also, I suggest you don't let your users send message directly with Socket.IO, but make an Ajax call to your main server instead (Drupal for ex.). That way you can check the user's identity more easily. (This scenario would be a fit for a chat based system that requires authentication)

Although this video tutorial is for EventMachine with Faye, the same logic could apply to your app: http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye